# How to integrate $x\ln(x+1)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms

I am trying to compute $\int x\ln (x+1)\, dx$. I tried integrating by parts and ended up with:
$$\int x\ln(x+1)\,dx = \frac{1}{2}x^2\ln(x+1) - \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{x^2}{x+1}\,dx$$ but I'm stuck here.

Comment: Hint: use $u = \ln x$ and $dv = x dx$

Comment: The integrand in your question is not the one in your title.

Comment: @GFauxPas Seems to be fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $x^2=x^2-1+1$ so that

$$\frac{x^2}{x+1}=\frac{x^2-1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{x+1}=(x-1)+\frac{1}{x+1} $$

Comment: Sneaky Sneaky! lol

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \dfrac{x^2}{x+1}dx = \int \dfrac{x^2-1}{x+1}dx + \int \dfrac{dx}{x+1} = \int (x-1) dx + \int \dfrac{dx}{x+1} = \dfrac{x^2}2 - x + \ln(x+1)+ c$$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:View $x^2$ as $x^2-1+1$ in the second part.

Comment: It's a little obscure.  Perhaps "as $(x-1)(x+1) + 1$" would be better help for a struggling calculus student?